# angularJS:ng-repeat orderby giving scrambled order while used conditionally

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

We have an ng-repeat as given below

```
 <table class="friend">
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Phone Number</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:(isSortRequired?'-name':'')">
  <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

which has to be sorted based on `name` only if the flag `isSortRequired` is `true`.otherwise no sorting is required. This works fine if the no. of records is less than or equal to 10 .if the number of records is greater than 10 and the flag is `false` the table shows the records in scrambled order.We want it to be displayed in the order as same as in the object.

Why is this behaviour? Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZBTYCCdpl6fgUcmlz67?p=preview) to illustrate the issue.

Comment: You can do one work around that filter the list before displaying. i.e when you get the data then call filter and store the result in one new list and display that new list in ng repeat

Comment: @Anita :-  Your thinking  is helps to solve this problem. But started a next problem for performance issue. please think about if she have 1000 of data's? then how can you do that?

Comment: you can ignore that part of storing in other list.You can apply filter on the list directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the angular documentation for the orderBy filter

> If no property is provided, then the array element itself is used to compare where sorting.

The scrambled effect is caused by angular adding a `$$hashKey` property to each object in your array. The `$$hasKey` is not guaranteed to be the same order of the initial array thus making them appear to be 'randomized'.

So either you order the array before-hand or use a custom filter that applies the orderBy filter only if you need to ordering.

A custom filter could look something like this

```
.filter('filter', ['$filter', function($filter)
{
  var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
  return function(input, property, use)
  {
    return use ? oderBy(input, property) : input;
  };
}
```

Comment: ordering the array beforehand is not an option because the user has provision to click on any column to get it sorted asc/desc as he wish.Custom filter is also giving the same behaviour

Comment: This behavior can be accomplished by a custom filter.

Comment: .filter('customOrder',function($filter)
        {
            return function(friend, prediate,isSortRequired){
              if(!isSortRequired)
              return friend;
              else
              {
                var result = $filter("orderBy")(friend, prediate);
                  return result;
              }
                
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by use `reverse` option in your order by

I have changed your code

### Html changes

```
 <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th> 
      **<a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=!reverse">Name</a>**</th>// changes here
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    **<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">**// changes here
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I have added a scope object in your controller for name sorting

```
$scope.predicate = '-name';
```

### Script changes

```
<script>
  angular.module('orderByExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.isSortRequired = true;
      $scope.friends =
          [{name:'john', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
           {name:'mary', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
           {name:'mike', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
           {name:'julie', phone:'555-8765', age:29},{name:'A', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
           {name:'B', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
           {name:'C', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
           {name:'D', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
           {name:'E', phone:'555-8765', age:29},{name:'F', phone:'555-1212', age:10},
           {name:'G', phone:'555-9876', age:19},
           {name:'H', phone:'555-4321', age:21},
           {name:'I', phone:'555-5678', age:35},
           {name:'J', phone:'555-8765', age:29}];
    }]);

    $scope.predicate = '-name';// ans also some change here
</script>
```

I have updated your [plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gGkyI8Q9cVLyzMZsOrDJ?p=preview)

> The *plunker* only help to sort the name column only, if you want to sort all columns, then you need to do the same way for your all columns.

Comment: the records are not in the order as specified in the object by deafult. I was looking for that  alone.the `reverse` was pretty fine.